# Angular Ng-Select items not updating

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngselect

Hi I was trying to update the items from the server when user types something.

this is what I tried so far

```
<form [formGroup]="mainForm" class="exclusive-search-componenet">
<fieldset class="m-0">
<ng-select #searchBox [items]="typeAhead"
           [loading]="typeAheadLoading"
           bindLabel="mainTitle"
           bindValue="id"
           [virtualScroll]="true"
           placeholder="search events, tags and more ..."
           formControlName="token"
           class="exclusive-search-select"
           (focus)="fetchTypeAheadFocus()"
           (search)="fetchTypeAheadSearch($event)"
           >

  <ng-template ng-notfound-tmp let-searchTerm="searchTerm">
    <div class="ng-option disabled">
      No record found for <span *ngIf="searchTerm">'{{searchTerm}}'</span>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-i="index">
    <div class="media align-items-center">
      <div class="avatar bg-primary mr-1">
        <div class="avatar-content">
          <i class="avatar-icon bx bx-show"></i>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="media-body mt-25 mb-25">
        <h6 class="m-0" [textContent]="item.mainTitle"></h6>
        <span class="font-size-small" [textContent]="item.subTitle"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
    <div class="media align-items-center">
      <div class="avatar mr-1 bg-primary bg-lighten-2">
        <span class="avatar-content">LD</span>
      </div>
      <div class="media-body mt-25 mb-25">
        <h6 class="m-0" [textContent]="item.mainTitle"></h6>
        <span class="font-size-small" [textContent]="item.subTitle"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-exclusive-search',
  templateUrl: './exclusive-search.component.html',
})
export class ExclusiveSearch implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

typeAheadLoading: boolean;
typeAhead: Array<IExclusivesTypeAhead>;
mainForm: FormGroup;

searchToken: string;
searchSubscription: Subscription;

constructor(
  private readonly formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  private readonly httpService: HttpService) {

  this.typeAhead = new Array<IExclusivesTypeAhead>();
  this.searchToken = 'searchToken';
  this.buildForm();

}

ngOnInit(): void {}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.searchSubscription.unsubscribe();
}

buildForm(): void {
  const formGroup = {
    token: [null],
    [this.searchToken]: [null]
  };

this.mainForm = this.formBuilder.group(formGroup);

this.searchSubscription = this.mainForm.get(this.searchToken)
  .valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(500), distinctUntilChanged())
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.fetchTypeAheadHelper(this.mainForm.value[this.searchToken]);
  });
}

fetchTypeAheadFocus() {
  if (!this.typeAhead || this.typeAhead.length <= 0) {
    this.fetchTypeAheadHelper();
  }
}

fetchTypeAheadSearch(event: {}) {
  const token = event["term"];
  if (token) {
    this.mainForm.patchValue({
      [this.searchToken]: token
    });
  }
}

private fetchTypeAheadHelper(token: string = null) {
  this.typeAheadLoading = true;

  this.httpService.post<ICommonResponse>(Api.build(Api.exclusives, Api.typeAhead), { mainTitle: token, pageSize: 4 })
  .pipe(finalize(() => { this.typeAheadLoading = false }))
  .subscribe((response: ICommonResponse) => {
    switch (response.status) {
      case CommonStatus.Success:
        /*LIST IS NOT UPDATING ITS ALWAYS GIVING ME NO RECORD FOUND*/
        /*But when i blur and focus it again my new list is showing again*/
        this.typeAhead = response.data as Array<IExclusivesTypeAhead>;
        break;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

It working for the very first time or in focus
I'm new to this technology, tried various ways none of them are working please guide in the correct path
I tried close() before binding and open() after bind values its worked but search tern is going off 
thanks a lot

Comment: At secons time, is the http request being sent or not? If sent , is it returning data but data not being updated or not retuning data?

Comment: send time also its htiing http data aslo coming and binding to this.typeahead but not showing in the dropdown list but its still there, when click somewhere and click again on ng-select those updated list is showing. I think its change detection issue